# Pagination in single.php

Tags: php, posts, pagination, single

I have a problem with the pagination on a single.php page.

The idea is to have a list of my created posts (the excert, the title and a link to the post) on the post page (single.php) that shares the same category with the one that I'm viewing.

I have a custom loop that filters the category and the maximum number of posts to show per page, but the next page doesn't exist (even manually writing the: *[www.example.com/my-post/page/2](http://www.example.com/my-post/page/2)*, */?page=2/* or */2/*). It redirects me to [www.example.com/my-post/](http://www.example.com/my-post/)

If I manually change the $page variable, the posts listed change to the next ones that should be shown.

Any idea why the links in the single.php don't work as in a page template?

Here is the code of my custom wp_query and the pagination (I know its a bit awkward, but on my other page Template works perfectly :

```
the_content(); // The post edited in the WP editor //

$number_of_posts = get_field('number_of_posts');

$arg = array(
'post_type'   => 'post',            
'showposts'   => -1,    
'post_status' => 'any',
'cat'         => $actual_cat_id,    
); 

$count_query = new WP_Query($arg);  
$total_post = $count_query->post_count;
$total_pages = ceil($total_post/$number_of_posts); 

if (get_query_var('paged') == null) {   
$page= 1;                           
} else {
$page = get_query_var('paged');     
}
                                        
$arguments = array(     
 'post_type'    => 'post',  
 'post__not_in' => array($actual_post_id),  
 'showposts'    => $number_of_posts,            
 'paged'       => $page,    
 'orderby'     => 'date',               
 'order'       => 'DESC',                   
 'post_status'  => 'any',                   
 'cat'         => $actual_cat_id,   
);

$paged = $page;

$my_query = new WP_Query($arguments);

while...

// THE LOOP (with the excert and the title for each post) //

...endwhile

wp_reset_postdata();

// PGINATION WITH ARROWS //
if ($total_pages == 1) { 

 <div>
  <span> &lt;&lt; </span>
  <span> &lt; </span>
  <span> PAG <?php echo $paged."/". $total_pages; ?> </span>
  <span> &gt; </span>
  <span> &gt;&gt; </span>
 </div>

 } elseif ($paged == 1) {
  $paged_siguiente = $paged+1; 
  <div>
    <span> &lt;&lt; </span>
    <span> &lt; </span>
    <span> PAG <?php echo $paged."/". $total_pages; ?> </span>
    <a href="?paged=<?php echo $paged_siguiente; ?>"> <span> &gt; </span> </a>
    <a href="?paged=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>"> <span> &gt;&gt; </span> </a> 
  </div>

 } elseif ($paged>1 && $paged<$total_pages) {
  $paged_siguiente = $paged+1;
  $paged_atras = $paged-1;

   <div>
    <a href="?paged=1"> <span> &lt;&lt; </span> </a>
    <a href="?paged=<?php echo $paged_atras; ?>"> <span> &lt; </span> </a>
    <span> PAG <?php echo $paged."/". $total_pages; ?> </span>
    <a href="?paged=<?php echo $paged_siguiente; ?>"> <span> &gt; </span> </a>
    <a href="?paged=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>"> <span> &gt;&gt; </span> </a>
   </div> 
} elseif ($paged == $total_pages) { 
 $paged_atras = $paged-1; 

 <div>
    <a href="?paged=1"> <span> &lt;&lt; </span> </a>
    <a href="?paged=<?php echo $paged_atras; ?>"> <span> &lt; </span> </a>
    <span> PAG <?php echo $paged."/". $total_pages; ?> </span>
    <span> &gt; </span>
    <span> &gt;&gt; </span>
 </div> 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom loops do not produce pagination like that.

You have two options:

1. Use custom archive page and provide custom php template for that (i.e. *archive-my_name.php*), in this custom template you could provide all other necessary content. Then you could use standard built-in pagination functions https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/
2. Continue in the direction you started, with single.php, but you would need to provide your own pagination, together with rewrites for custom pages. Again, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/#methods-for-displaying-pagination-links provides starting point for that.

I advise using option 1. as easier.

Comment: Thx for your advice. I tried the 1st option, but my archive-$posttype.php with the custom post type redirects me to the index.php template. I don't know if I understand your solution/idea

Comment: It should not redirect to index.php. I now see my mistake, I assumed you are using custom post types, but you are using regular post types. Index.php is the fallback if no other appropriate template is found. I correct myself, you should use archive.php or category.php if you want to have special template for category. You can customize permalinks in dashboards -> settings -> permalinks. And open that page just in case because mere opening of that page flushes permalink rewrite cache, so any incorrect redirects should be fixed automatically.

Comment: Thx for your help, but finally this code in my function.php solve the problem:

`add_filter('redirect_canonical','pif_disable_redirect_canonical');

function pif_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {
if (is_single()) $redirect_url = false;

return $redirect_url;
}`